# What does google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize) function exactly mean?

Tags: javascript, search-engine, google-api

While coding JavaScript and Ajax, there is no proper documentation for this function. I searched this term using `api src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"` and `searchControl.execute("abhilashm86");`.

How is this `google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize)` called internally? Is this function just for a new search term when the user clears previous search and starts a new one? 
How exactly does `google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize)` get trigerred?

Answer (score 10):

Your initialize function will be called when your document (including the Google API) is fully loaded.  So you should wrap any code that uses the API in the function you pass in:

E.g.

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
{
   var searcher = new google.search.SearchControl();
   // More code that depends on the API.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#AJAX_Loader) says:

> Use google.setOnLoadCallback to register the specified handler function to be called once the document loads instead of GSearch.setOnLoadCallback.